# AngularJS - ng-click and ng-show

Tags: javascript, angularjs, overlay, hide, show

I have a map with some markers on it. On click, each marker is opening a overlay-div.

```
 <div class="map" ng-init="loadall()">
            <a ng-click="details.show=!details.show" href="#/dealer/{{marker.id}}" class="marker" style="left:{{marker.coordleft}}px;top:{{marker.coordtop}}px" ng-repeat="marker in dealer"></a>    
        </div>
```

**it's opening this div:**

```
<div ng-show="details.show">      
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

**Problem:**
If the div is already open (details.show == true) my customer noticed, that if you leave it open and click on an other marker on the map, the div closes again.

**What I want to achieve:**
If the div is already open, just load the new content into the ng-view without closing and reopening the div again.

Is this possible?

EDIT:

**My routes:**

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
      when('/dealer/:id', {templateUrl: 'files/tpl/dealer-details.html?20', controller: 'DealerDetailsCtrl', activetab: 'details'}).
      when('/dealermessage/:id', {templateUrl: 'files/tpl/dealer-message.html?124', controller: 'DealerMessageCtrl', activetab: 'message'}).
      when('/dealersendmessage/:id', {templateUrl: 'files/tpl/dealer-details.html?8', controller: 'DealerDetailsCtrl', activetab: 'details'}).
      otherwise({redirectTo: '/dealer'});
}]);
```

If a marker has been clicked, the first route and controller are loading.Is this helping out?

**EDIT No.2:**
The "marker/div toggle is working now but I have now a strange behavior of the opened overlay.

**Example:**
When I open "Marker 1" the div is opening fine. When the div for "Marker 1" is open, I can click on "Marker 2" and the div refreshes with the content of "Marker 2". But when I now click on "Marker 1" the div suddenly closes.
How can I stop it?

Comment: I don't understand something here. Is `ng-click="details.show=!details.show` a toggle link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Still don't understand it much, but **you keep only one model to toggle several markers**. So if you click on one marker to open, another marker will close it, since you don't keep the marker's state. You probably need something like:

```
<div ng-repeat="marker in dealer">
   <a ng-click="details.show=toggle(marker)" href="#/dealer/{{marker.id}}" 
      class="marker" style="left:{{marker.coordleft}}px;top:{{marker.coordtop}}px"></a>
</div>
```

In your controller you define the `toggle` function:

```
$scope.toggle = function(marker) {
   marker.show = !marker.show;

   return marker.show;
};
```

Comment: The toggle isn't the problem. It works fine. But my client wants, that, IF the overlay is open (show == true) and a customer clicks on the next marker, the content shall be reloaded with the new id instead of closing the overlay.

Comment: @Marek123 well, I would agree that toggle probably toggles one marker correctly, but you're trying to get your ng-click to do more than just toggle now, right?  If you tried what asgoth suggested, did it work?  If it didn't work, what happens?

Comment: Yes, I tried the solution from asgoth and it worked perfectly. Thank you.  
May I ask for some "offtopic". Is it possible to determine, which marker has been clicked and mark this marker with ng-class?

Comment: marker.show should indicate which marker was clicked, so just add an ng-class directive that uses it:  `ng-class={someClassYouHave: marker.show}`

Comment: I get this error: Error: Syntax Error: Token 'undefined' not a primary expression at column NaN of the expression [{active_marker:] starting at [{active_marker:].
    at Error (<anonymous>)

Comment: It works now. But I still have some errors, check my edit please.

Answer (score 1):

Your ng-click handler needs to have more logic (as @asgoth's answer shows).

Another possible solution (that does not modify the dealer data): pass `$event` into your ng-click handler

```
<a ng-click="handleOverlay($event)" ... ></a>
```

Then store the srcElement on $scope  (`$scope.openMarker = ev.srcElement`).  handleOverlay() can then determine, for each click, if the click is happening on the element that is already open, or a new one.

We don't know how you are reloading ng-view, so if that is an issue, we'd need to see more code.  E.g., are you loading a different controller for each new view?  If so, you may need to store the srcElement on a service or rootScope (i.e., something that will survive a view/controller change).

Comment: I added the routes to my initial post, is this helping you ?

Comment: Each click is likely creating a new controller (verify by adding `console.log('in ctrl')` as the first line of DealerDetailsCtrl.  Therefore, you'll need to store the srcElement related to the currently open overlay in $rootScope or in a service (or try what @asgoth suggested).   Inject $rootScope into your DealerDetailsCtrl to get access to it:  function DealerDetailsCtrl($scope, $rootScope) { ... }

Comment: It works now. But I still have some errors, check my edit please.

Comment: Now that I look at it some more, I don't think asgoth's answer will work because it sets up a toggle for each marker, hence the behavior you are seeing.  I think you should try my approach -- save the currently open marker (or element) on $rootScope (or in a service).  Have the click handler determine if the current click is associated with the marker that was last clicked or not, and act accordingly.  If you still have issues, set up a fiddle or plunkr.

Answer (score 0):

So I followed asgoth's solution and also extended it to fix the issue mentioned by Marek123. Below is my solution :

```
$scope.selectedMarker = {};
$scope.toggle = function(marker) {
  //assuming you have a key "id" in each dealer
  if (marker.id !== $scope.selectedMarker.id) {
      _.each($scope.delear, function(value, index) {
        $scope.delear[index].show = false;
      });
    }
   marker.show = !marker.show;
   return marker.show;
};
```